# How to create single-pixel wide edges?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When using the Edge option on the renderer, it creates several-pixels wide borders.

[on blender http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01k.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01k.png)

When creating pixel arts, though, it is fundamental never to have 2 black pixels in a row:

[somewhere else http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01j.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/01j.png)

How to achieve this effect on Blender?